# How to change the color UINavigation bar's separator line

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am getting a separator line in UINavigation bar, how can I remove this?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
Updated - Attached full screen screen-shot. [image]

Comment: It does not seem like a UINavigation bar. Are you using a table view on the view?

Comment: This is a simple navigation bar, i had just changed the color of bar to white and hide the back button.

Comment: i am not sure about the problem. Can you post the scenario/code/bigger screenshot?

Comment: why did you changed the color? do you want it to be hidden in this particular view controller?

Comment: you can't do this better create your own customized navigation bar..

Comment: @all - i want to have a white coloured navigation bar on view, not able to remove the separator line.

Comment: Well, the best option for you is the create a subclass of UINavigation bar and in the draw rect method add an image that fulfills your purpose. You current approach will result in the same way as iOS manages the control itself so there is nothing we can do to override it. Not that I know of. You can check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430785/1351911) if you want.

P.S. If you find any turn around please let all know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're targeting for iOS 5 and newer, you can set an arbitrary background image for UINavigationBar like this

```
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you need to support iOS 4, try subclassing UINavigationBar and overriding `drawRect:` method.

Comment: i have to finally go with this, which i don't want earlier. Thanks!!

Comment: It works for me in simulator, but on the device (I tested on an iPhone 4), it sticks a 1 pixel white line... Is there any trick?

Comment: The only way I found to really remove it (on device and on simulator), is to add a overlay view with 1 pixel high at the bottom of the navigation bar. My luck I have a BaseViewController from where every view controller is inherted. So, it was one change to fix it all.